# How to find what code created some data?

Tags: tools, binary-analysis

I'd like to be able to point to a buffer in memory likely on the heap and have a tool tell me which part of the binary created the data in the file.
What tools can do that for me?

Comment: If the data is always at the same address, you could use a breakpoint at that address trough a debugger (Olly, Immunity, Cheat engine) and see what function accesses that part of the memory. If it has a dynamic address I'ld examine what's in that memory location, and try to figure out when/what put's it there. Start with setting a global breakpoint on memory related APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a debugger like gdb, you could set a hardware breakpoint at the heap address. From the [gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html):

> hbreak args
>
> Set a hardware-assisted breakpoint. ... These targets will generate traps when a program accesses some data or instruction address that is assigned to the debug registers.

After setting a hardware breakpoint, the debugger will trap when the memory is accessed for a read or a write.

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging `PE` executable (Windows), you can use the `!heap -p` options of `WinDbg`.

You can read about it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-heap).

Note that you will have to enable it using `gflags.exe` - It's also mentioned in the document above.